# Pull Limes out of integral

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $f_\epsilon$ converge pointwise to $f$ for $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ and let $f_\epsilon$ and $f$ be integrable.

Can I swap integral and limes in this case?
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_\Omega f_{\epsilon}(x) dx
= 
\int_\Omega \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}  f_{\epsilon}(x) dx
=
\int_\Omega f(x) dx
$$

I tried to apply dominated convergence, by using $f + 1$ as the upper bound function, but because of pointwise convergence it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general one cannot interchange the limit and integral. By way of a counter example, consider the sequence $(f_n) \subset L^1(\mathbb{R})$ given by
$$
f_n(x) :=  \mathbf{1}_{[n,n+1)}(x).
$$
Clearly, $f_n(x) \to 0$ for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. However, 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n\,\mathrm{d}m
= \lim_{n \to \infty} 1  = 1 \neq \int_{\mathbb{R}} 0\,\mathrm{d}m.
\end{align*}
Without additional assumptions (e.g. monotonicity or uniform domination by an integrable function), the above shows that one cannot freely pass the limit into the integral.

---

Even if the measure space is finite one cannot *necessarily* take the limit inside the integral. Indeed, consider the Lebesgue measure $m$ on $[0,1]$ and define a sequence $g_n$ on $[0,1]$ via the rule
$$
g_n(x) := n \mathbf{1}_{\left[0, \frac{1}{n}\right)}(x), \quad \forall n \geq 1.
$$
Again, it is clear that $g_n(x) \to 0$ for almost every $x \in [0,1]$. However, as above,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0,1]} g_n\,\mathrm{d}m = 1 \neq \int_{[0,1]} 0\,\mathrm{d}m = 0.
$$

---

**Additional observations**

Even when one cannot dominate by an integrable function, there are still situations in which one *can* pass the limit into the integral. In my experience, the following theorem has turned out to be particularly useful:

> **Theorem**. Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ converging almost everywhere to a function $f$. If $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ has finite measure and $(f_n)$ is bounded in $L^p(E)$ for some $1 < p < \infty$, then 
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_E f_n\,\mathrm{d}m = \int_E f\,\mathrm{d}m.
> $$
>   In fact, one has $f_n \to f$ in $L^1(E)$.